# CustomAlert Message overWrite

Tags: swift, struct, uialertview, uialertcontroller

my model :

```swift
struct Model : Codable {
    let title : String
    var target : Int
    var read : Int
    let mean : String
    let useful : String
}
```

and I create custom alert messages model:

```swift
class MyAlert  {
    struct Constants {
        static let backgroundAlphaTo : CGFloat = 0.6
    }

    private var backgroundView : UIView = {
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
        backgroundView.alpha = 0
        return backgroundView
    }()

    private let alertView : UIView = {
        let alertView = UIView()
        alertView.backgroundColor = .white
        alertView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return alertView
    }()
    
    private var myTargetView : UIView?
    
    func showAlert(with title :String , message : String , on ViewController : UIViewController){
        guard let targetView = ViewController.view else {
            return
        }
        myTargetView = targetView
        
        backgroundView.frame = targetView.bounds
        targetView.addSubview(backgroundView)
        targetView.addSubview(alertView)
        
        alertView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 40, y: -300, width: targetView.frame.size.width-80, height: 300
        )
        
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
                                    x: 0,
                                    y: 0,
                                    width: alertView.frame.size.width,
                                    height: 80))
        titleLabel.text = title
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        alertView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
                                    x: 0,
                                    y: 80,
                                    width: alertView.frame.size.width,
                                    height: 170))
        
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        alertView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(
                                x: 0,
                                y: alertView.frame.size.height-50,
                                width: alertView.frame.size.width,
                                height: 50))
        
        alertView.addSubview(button)
        button.setTitle("Kapat", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dissmissAlert), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = Constants.backgroundAlphaTo
        } completion: { (done) in
            if done {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                    self.alertView.center = targetView.center
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc  func dissmissAlert() {
        guard let targetView = myTargetView else {
            return
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.alertView.frame = CGRect(
                x: 40, y: targetView.frame.size.height, width: targetView.frame.size.width-80, height: 300
                
            )}, completion: {done in
                if done {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
                    }, completion: {done in
                        if done {
                            self.alertView.removeFromSuperview()
                            self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                        
                    })
                }
                
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and I have segmentController :

```swift
@objc func ButtonTapped( _ sender : UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        customAlert.showAlert(with: zikirs.title, message: zikirs.mean, on: self)
    } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        customAlert.showAlert(with: zikirs.title, message: zikirs.useful, on: self)
    }
}

private func dismissAlert(){
    customAlert.dissmissAlert()
}
```

the problem here is the first message is normal but the second message overwrites the other.
[image]

how can I overcome this problem. I think this is from the inheritance property of the Classes. but I wanted to do my CustomAlert model with Struct because @objc can be only classes

Comment: i think headline not related with question

Comment: that is why i think headline should be more specific.

Comment: Most likely this happens because you don’t remove the `titleLabel` from the main view

Comment: what should I do

Comment: Treat the labels like the views. Declare them on the top level and remove them on dismiss.

Comment: self.alertView.removeFromSuperview() here I'm removing them all ??

Comment: Yes, but the alertView is quasi a constant and the labels are still attached to it. The next time you use it new labels are added.

Comment: Vadian please compile my code.

Comment: for view in self.alertView.subviews {
         view.removeFromSuperview()
     } I found what I was looking for. very good run thanks vadian.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't remove the labels and the button from `alertView` but add new ones on the next call.

My suggestion is to assign tags to the views and create them only the first time

```
class MyAlert  {
    struct Constants {
        static let backgroundAlphaTo : CGFloat = 0.6
    }

    private var backgroundView : UIView = {
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
        backgroundView.alpha = 0
        return backgroundView
    }()

    private let alertView : UIView = {
        let alertView = UIView()
        alertView.backgroundColor = .white
        alertView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return alertView
    }()
    
    private var myTargetView : UIView?
    
    func showAlert(with title :String , message : String , on ViewController : UIViewController){
        guard let targetView = ViewController.view else {
            return
        }
        myTargetView = targetView
        
        backgroundView.frame = targetView.bounds
        targetView.addSubview(backgroundView)
        targetView.addSubview(alertView)
        
        alertView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 40, y: -300, width: targetView.frame.size.width-80, height: 300
        )
        
        if let titleLabel = alertView.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
             titleLabel.text = title
        } else {      
            let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: alertView.frame.size.width,
                height: 80))
            titleLabel.tag = 100
            titleLabel.text = title
            titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
            alertView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        }
        
        if let messageLabel = alertView.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
            messageLabel.text = message
        } else {
            let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: 80,
                width: alertView.frame.size.width,
                height: 170))
            
            messageLabel.tag = 101
            messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            messageLabel.text = message
            messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
            alertView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        }
        
        if alertView.viewWithTag(102) == nil {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: alertView.frame.size.height-50,
                width: alertView.frame.size.width,
                height: 50))
            
            button.tag = 102
            alertView.addSubview(button)
            button.setTitle("Kapat", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dissmissAlert), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = Constants.backgroundAlphaTo
        } completion: { (done) in
            if done {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                    self.alertView.center = targetView.center
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc  func dissmissAlert() {
        guard let targetView = myTargetView else {
            return
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.alertView.frame = CGRect(
                x: 40, y: targetView.frame.size.height, width: targetView.frame.size.width-80, height: 300
                
            )}, completion: {done in
                if done {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
                    }, completion: {done in
                        if done {
                            self.alertView.removeFromSuperview()
                            self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                        
                    })
                }
                
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: if let messageLabel = alertView.viewWithTag(101) {
            messageLabel.text = message                                                                                       }.   "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'text' "

Comment: I solve with for-loop:                                                                                                                          for view in self.alertView.subviews {                                                   view.removeFromSuperview()                                                                                              }